# Print outputs next to each other markdown

Tags: r, printf, markdown

I'm searching for a solution where I can print multiple outputs from a loop next to each other in markdown.

The function `summary` is used as example here.

Example:

```
for (val in names(mtcars)){
  cat("\n\n", val, "\n\n")
  print(summary(mtcars[val]))
}
```

the output is a lot of summarys, which I want to arrange next to each other in markdown. In my pdf I get a lot of pages through this.

[image: output]

Of course I could save every variable from `summary` and print it in a table. But since this is in my case very unelegant, I'm looking for another solution. Maybe it's possible to catch the whole output and put that in a table for markdown to print? A fixed length for formatting is not an issue.

Comment: What about the whole sets of column in the summary call? `summary(mtcars)`

Comment: @Maël it's not about the specific function summary. It's just for the example. It might be a possibility, that I transform my data beforhand. But still looking, if there is an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could look at the `modelsummary` package:

````
---
title: "Summary"
format: pdf
---  

```{r}
#| echo: false
library(modelsummary)
datasummary(All(mtcars) ~ Min + P25 + P50 + Mean + P75 + Max, 
            data = mtcars)

datasummary_skim(mtcars)
```
````

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It's not about the function summary. It's just an example.